# UITextField Swift Mostrar error FloatLabelTextField

Tags: swift, xcode

Estoy utilizando la clase que saque de GitHub

```
FloatLabelTextField
```

> https://github.com/FahimF/FloatLabelFields/blob/master/FloatLabelFields/FloatLabelTextField.swift

La cual realiza el efecto de subir el `placeholder` como titulo

Lo que necesito es poder mostrar un detalle de error a la hora de validar , lo quisiera poner abajo , actualmente el fix que encontre es utilizar los siguientes metodos 
 que son una extesion de `UIVIEW`

```
  func addBottomBorderError(errorDetail: String) {

        let height = 1.5
        let color = UIColor.red
        let separation = 0
        let border = UIView()
        border.backgroundColor = color
        border.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(border)

        let label : UILabel = UILabel()
        label.text = errorDetail
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 20)
        label.textColor = UIColor.red

        border.addSubview(label)

        border.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: border,
                                                attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                                relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                                toItem: nil,
                                                attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                                multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(height)))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: border,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom,
                                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                              toItem: self,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom,
                                              multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(separation)))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: border,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,
                                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                              toItem: self,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,
                                              multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: border,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,
                                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                              toItem: self,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,
                                              multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }
    func addBottomBorderCleanError(textField: FloatLabelTextField) {

        let height = 1.5
        let color = Utils.Color.COLOR_82C341
        let separation = 0
        let border = UIView()
        border.backgroundColor = color
        border.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(border)


        textField.detail = "ff"
        textField.detailColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_2B5034

//        label.text = textField.detail
//        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
//        label.numberOfLines = 2
//        label.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 20)
//        label.textColor = UIColor.red
//
        border.addSubview(textField.detailLabel)


        border.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: border,
                                                attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                                relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                                toItem: nil,
                                                attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,
                                                multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(height)))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: border,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom,
                                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                              toItem: self,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom,
                                              multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(separation)))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: border,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,
                                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                              toItem: self,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,
                                              multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: border,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,
                                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                              toItem: self,
                                              attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,
                                              multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }
```

El problema de esto es que como se agrega dinamicamente no puedo acceder al label que genere para borrarle los datos , y ponerle una view por arriba para hacer parecer que elimine el texto no me parece nada bueno ,

Mi pregunta es tienen una mejor idea de como poder agregar este texto por debajo de las cajas y luego poder borrarlos, el metodo que setea el error se realiza al presionar el boton , y el segunda se llama en el evento de change text de la caja , cualquier idea me viene bien , no puedo usar otras cosas porque mi caja ya utiliza la de Float para el efecto , desde ya gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías hacer que `label` sea una propiedad de tu clase (le cambiaría el nombre a `errorLabel` o algo más descriptivo), para poder acceder a ella fuera del método.

```
class FloatLabelTextField {
    var errorLabel: UILabel?

    func addBottomBorderError(errorDetail: String) {
        ...

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = errorDetail
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 20)
        label.textColor = UIColor.red

        border.addSubview(label)

        errorLabel = label

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: el problema con esto es que una vez que lo agrega con el border.addsubview , si yo despeus hago el otro que setea vacio el texto , el anterior ya esta puesto en la vista no lo puedo editar? como podria resolver esto se te ocurre algo? nose si me explique , como ya lo agrego a esa label con x texto , despues no puedo acceder a esa label para editar ese texto solo estaria pisandolo arriba y si piso arriba con un vcio en realidad no se borro el anterior

Comment: Cuando quieras quitar el texto, puedes simplemente asignarle el texto vacío (`self.errorLabel.text = ""`), o quitar la etiqueta `errorLabel` de la vista (`self.borderView.removeSubview(self.errorLabel); self.errorLabel = nil`)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Marcos funciono de 10 ,